# What proves you are the owner of a domain name

Tags: dns

I have never registered a domain before. I have been wondering, when you buy one, what makes you the owner? Is it linked to your email address or are you given something like a token so that when you want to link it to a host you provide the token to prove you are the owner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't programming related. Generally when you register a domain you provide contact details which are added to the domain. This is shown when you query whois data; https://www.whois.com/whois/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing directly proves you own the domain.

You tell your hoster "I want to use this domain on your webspace" (for hosting on a shared server) and then they tell you how to configure your DNS server. Or if you have a server with a dedicated IP, then you just set that in your DNS server on your own.

Proof you own a domain is only required for some third party services, like creating certificates for domain names and alike. This proof is either preformed by proofing that you own the server to which the domain currently points to with it's `A` (IPv4) or `AAAA` (IPv6) record, or you are required to set a custom `TXT` record to prove you have control over the DNS server.

When you order the domain, you got to assign a DNS server for it. Either one you have set up yourself, or typically one managed by your domain seller. Everything beyond that is just configuration of that server. Your registrar takes care that the chosen DNS server is correctly used for your domain.

Comment: I know this might sound silly @Ext3h, if my host asks me to link my domain name with my website, and I entered `facebook.com` there should be a way to know that am not the owner of `facebook.com`. My question is how do they know? Is there some kind verification method?

Comment: You can enter `facebook.com` if you like. For your host, that only means that if an incoming request comes for `facebook.com`, it's going to be served with the content of your webspace. Expect that you don't have access to the DNS record for `facebook.com`, so all requests will just go to the original severs and what you told your hoster to configure never has any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Your possession of a domain name comes down to a contract between you and the holder of the domain under which yours lives, with ICANN sitting at the top as the owners of the root domain. So Verisign has a contract with ICANN saying that they hold `.COM`, and if you want a domain under `.COM`, you enter into a contract with Verisign. In practice, Verisign has farmed out the contract-writing to oodles of other companies called "registrars", like gandi.net. So you pay them money, they tell Verisign the domain is yours and that's it. Exactly how picky a particular registrar is about knowing who they're selling a name to varies a lot. In some cases it's enough that you have a valid credit card and can log into the registrar's website, in other cases you may have to prove that you are a resident of a certain country.

Comment: The resident constraints or assimilated are not from the registrars but are made by some registries. So the registrars just have to pass the regulations.